# Assembly, passing arguments into procedures

Tags: assembly, stack, arguments, masm

I need to know if I'm still not fully understanding how passing arguments into procedures works, because I have to know if it is what is causing problems in my program.

Say I have two DWORD variables, named var1 and var2. I want to call a function called addtwo, does the same thing that the examples in the book do. But I also want to call within it a function called addtwo2 (separate to avoid recursion) using the exact same variables. in the main, would I do this

```
push OFFSET var1
push OFFSET var2
call addtwo
```

then in addtwo, do this

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
```

and to call the first var, I would do [esp + 8] and the second var [esp + 12].
Now, say I want to pass these same along into the addtwo2. Would I do the same thing as in main, and do

```
push OFFSET var1
push OFFSET var2
call addtwo2
```

then in addtwo2, do

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
```

and use the same [esp + 8 and 12] to call the specific variables? Then, at the end of each, put in ret to clear the stacks?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your question: yes.

With `push` and `call` and also with `pop` and `ret` you change the stackpointer (`ESP`) downwards and upwards. So `ESP` in `addtwo2` points "not really" to the same memory location - i.e. not to the same variable - as `ESP` in `addtwo1`.